# What's the speed of the train with our point of reference being the person who's moving inside the train?

Tags: kinematics, inertial-frames, velocity, speed, displacement

A person moving in a train with the speed of **1m/s** to the right, while the train is moving in the same direction with the speed of **10m/s**

From the person's point of view "considering that the person is our point of reference" the velocity of the train is 0?

A long discussion was made about this question in one of my classes, and I haven't reached a convincing conclusion.

Since the train is moving the person with it, they move as one object, then the movement of the train from the person's perspective is 0! even if he's moving INSIDE the train.

On the other hand, the professor insisted that the speed of the train from the person's point of reference is 9, as if the person was outside of the train.

So who's tackling this correctly?

[image]

Comment: It helps if you say "velocity of X _in a coordinate frame that is attached to Y_." The velocity of the train in a coordinate frame that is attached to the train is zero, the velocity of the train in a coordinate frame that is attached to the Earth is 10 and, in a coordinate frame attached to the walking person, it's -1.

Comment: As a former physics teacher: The question you are grappling with is so poorly worded that it is unanswerable.  Does the passenger pass a metre stick *on the train* in 1 sec?  Does the train pass a metre stick *on the ground* in 0.1 seconds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is in my opinion not phrased very precisely (the question you got in class, not your post). It is not clear in which frame of reference the person has velocity $1\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$ - it seemed to me that the given velocities are from an outside frame of reference. However, this would mean that the person is walking backwards (relative to the train), which seems to contradict the attached image. I will thus assume that the velocity of the person is measured with respect to the train.

If two objects have different velocities as seen from either one of the object's rest frames or another observer in another frame of reference, they *cannot* have the same velocity in *any* frame of reference. If you were to say, as in your example, that the person is moving with $1\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$ to the right in the train's frame of reference, the train has relative velocity $-1\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$ in the person's frame of reference.

If the person were to sit in the train (or stand, of course, but not walking), then the velocity of the train in the person's frame of reference were $0$. However, since the person is not stationary in the train, this cannot be the case.

In general, if you have two objects $A$ and $B$ moving relative to each other and $A$'s velocity in $B$'s frame of reference is $v$, then the velocity of $B$ in $A$'s reference frame is $-v$.
It is thus incorrect to say that the train's velocity in the person's frame is $9\mathrm{m}/\mathrm{s}$, *except* for when the velocity of the person is measured with respect to the ground, in which case the person would be moving backwards relative to the train.

Comment: I agree, since the person is not stationary, the velocity of the train to him wouldn't be 0, but in the case of him moving to the same direction, as the train, as shown in the image... wouldn't the train (to the person) have the same velocity as him, but in an opposite direction? so that from the person's perspective, the train is moving to the left at 1m/s with disregard to the actual speed in which the train is moving from the perspective of someone outside of the train?

Comment: @Rami yes this is correct, see my updated answer.